# Getting 404 error from postman when consuming an api exposed on wso2 apim 3.1.0 after migrating from aws kubernetes to OKE (kubernetes on OCI)

Tags: wso2, apim

Experiencing issues on WSO2 APIM 3.1.0 after migrating from AWS Kubernetes to OCI Kubernetes (OKE). Publisher and Devportal are accessible, displaying exposed APIs and API products. However, attempts to consume these APIs via Postman result in a 404 error.

**Actions taken**:

1. Republished APIs without success.
2. Removed and re-added APIs to some products, resolving issues for a few.

Few products still return 404 errors despite republishing and modifying APIs. Recreating is undesired due to customer disruption.

Seeking guidance on troubleshooting the persisting 404 errors.

**Actions taken**:

1. Republished APIs without success.
2. Removed and re-added APIs to some products, resolving issues for a few.